# didUpdateLocations and didUpdateToLocation

Tags: ios, location

Supporting both iOS 5 and 6, one should call `didUpdateLocations` from `didUpdateToLocation`.

How do you make the call and build the Locations array? Any code sample, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't call those routines. The system, CoreLocation specifically, calls them.

Answer (score 0):

I think this exact code is displayed in the WWDC 2012 session, [Staying on Track with Location Services](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=303):

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    [self locationManager:manager didUpdateLocations:@[newLocation]];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    // your location handling code
 }
```